# for loop only displays one item and the last item in the array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I have a for loop that loops through this array object. However there are a few things I am unsure of and do not understand. The first issue is that why is the loop only displaying one item from the array and not all of them? The other issue is that it is only displaying the last item from the array? I imagined it would display the first item but that is not the case. Any explanation to these issues is appreciated, thanks!

Javascript:

```
const rosterItems = [
  {
    img: '<img src="images/bryce.jpg" class="artist-image" alt="#">',
    resident: '<p>Resident: Bryce Methven</p>',
    bio: '<p>' +
         'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ' +
         'Culpa ex expedita doloremque, sunt eveniet, laboriosam totam at, debitis earum fugit eligendi quae. ' +
         'Perferendis ratione cum ipsum molestiae perspiciatis tempore aut?' +
         'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ' +
         'Culpa ex expedita doloremque, sunt eveniet, laboriosam totam at, debitis earum fugit eligendi quae. ' +
         'Perferendis ratione cum ipsum molestiae perspiciatis tempore aut?' +
         '</p>'
  },
  {
    img: '<img src="images/haptic.jpg" class="artist-image" alt="#">',
    resident: '<p>Resident: Haptic</p>',
    bio: '<p>' +
         'Haptic ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ' +
         'Culpa ex expedita doloremque, sunt eveniet, laboriosam totam at, debitis earum fugit eligendi quae. ' +
         'Perferendis ratione cum ipsum molestiae perspiciatis tempore aut?' +
         '</p>'
  },
  {
    img: '<img src="images/haptic.jpg" class="artist-image" alt="#">',
    resident: '<p>Resident: DJ Test</p>',
    bio: '<p>' +
         'Haptic ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ' +
         'Culpa ex expedita doloremque, sunt eveniet, laboriosam totam at, debitis earum fugit eligendi quae. ' +
         'Perferendis ratione cum ipsum molestiae perspiciatis tempore aut?' +
         '</p>'
  }
]

const rosterArtist = document.querySelector(".artist")
const rosterBio = document.querySelector(".bio")

for (let i = 0; i < rosterItems.length; i++) {

  let leftCol = `<div class="item">
                  ${rosterItems[i].img}
                  ${rosterItems[i].resident}
                  </div>`

  let rightCol = rosterItems[i].bio
    
  rosterArtist.innerHTML = leftCol
  rosterBio.innerHTML = rightCol

}
```

Html:

```
<div class="roster-gallery">
    <div class="artist">
    </div>
    <div class="artist-bio">
         <div class="bio">
         </div>
         <div class="pagination">
              <button class="previous">Previous</button>
              <button class="next">Next</button>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're overwriting the content of the elements instead of adding them: `.innerHTML = ...` -> `.innerHTML += ...` (`.insertAdjacentHTML()` is superior to `.innerHTML` and you should switch to that)

Comment: Oh I see now thank you! Why is `.insertAdjacentHTML()` superior to `.innerHTML`? I will look into this.

Comment: `.innerHTML` overwrites the complete content of the element and therefor forces the browser to parse and redraw everything in it. It also removes elements that might have event listeners on them. You then end with a bunch of unreachable event handlers. `.insertAdjacentHTML()` (and its other versions) only parse the content you call them with. They only _add_ new stuff and don't mess with existing one. No lost event handlers, the browser only has to draw the new stuff, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Html should be (you missed the event and for loop wont work for you)

```
<div class="roster-gallery">
<div class="artist">
</div>
<div class="artist-bio">
     <div class="bio">
     </div>
     <div class="pagination">
          <button class="previous" onclick="previous()">Previous</button>
          <button class="next"  onclick="next()">Next</button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and your javascript should be

```
    const rosterItems = [
  {
    img: '<img src="images/bryce.jpg" class="artist-image" alt="#">',
    resident: '<p>Resident: Bryce Methven</p>',
    bio: '<p>' +
         'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ' +
         'Culpa ex expedita doloremque, sunt eveniet, laboriosam totam at, debitis earum fugit eligendi quae. ' +
         'Perferendis ratione cum ipsum molestiae perspiciatis tempore aut?' +
         'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ' +
         'Culpa ex expedita doloremque, sunt eveniet, laboriosam totam at, debitis earum fugit eligendi quae. ' +
         'Perferendis ratione cum ipsum molestiae perspiciatis tempore aut?' +
         '</p>'
  },
  {
    img: '<img src="images/haptic.jpg" class="artist-image" alt="#">',
    resident: '<p>Resident: Haptic</p>',
    bio: '<p>' +
         'Haptic ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ' +
         'Culpa ex expedita doloremque, sunt eveniet, laboriosam totam at, debitis earum fugit eligendi quae. ' +
         'Perferendis ratione cum ipsum molestiae perspiciatis tempore aut?' +
         '</p>'
  },
  {
    img: '<img src="images/haptic.jpg" class="artist-image" alt="#">',
    resident: '<p>Resident: DJ Test</p>',
    bio: '<p>' +
         'Haptic ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. ' +
         'Culpa ex expedita doloremque, sunt eveniet, laboriosam totam at, debitis earum fugit eligendi quae. ' +
         'Perferendis ratione cum ipsum molestiae perspiciatis tempore aut?' +
         '</p>'
  }
]

const rosterArtist = document.querySelector(".artist")
const rosterBio = document.querySelector(".bio")

const maxPos = rosterItems.length;
let currentPos = 0; 

function previous(){
    if(currentPos>0){
    currentPos-=1;
  }
  showData();
}
function next(){
    if(currentPos<maxPos){
    currentPos+=1;
  }
  showData();
}
showData();
function showData(){
let leftCol = `<div class="item">
                  ${rosterItems[currentPos].img}
                  ${rosterItems[currentPos].resident}
                  </div>`

  let rightCol = rosterItems[currentPos].bio
    
  rosterArtist.innerHTML = leftCol
  rosterBio.innerHTML = rightCol
}
```

Comment: @Raidzz here is a fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/factedu/zwxbf42c/8/

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to do that! I was just looking for some explanations as to why the loop was displaying the last item from the array but thank you for showing me how to do the next step for my gallery!